# Open a file that I double-click with app created with Script Editor

Tags: applescript

I created an Application from Script Editor with this content:

```
do shell script "PATH=/Library/TeX/texbin:$PATH ¬
    open -n /Applications/Xournal++.app"
```

and I called it `/Users/enzotib/Applications/Xournal-mod.app`.

It works if I double click the application, then select a file `.xopp` to open.

The question is: how should I modify the script, so that I can <strike>associate the file extension `.xopp` with the application</strike> open the file that I double-click with the application?

**Edit**

I changed the title, that was "Associate file type with app created from Script Editor", because I realised it was misleading.

Comment: You need to edit the **Info.plist** to include the `CFBundleDocumentTypes` you want associated with your app.

Comment: @red_menace: can you be more specific, please? I do not understand what to do

Comment: The [CFBundleDocumentTypes](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-101685) key in the **Info.plist** is an array of dictionaries that associate document types with your app.  You can check out the **Info.plist** of existing apps, such as Preview or TextEdit, for examples.  The default app to open a particular file can also be set from the Finder's **Get Info** window.

Comment: @red_menace: the problem is not the association, that I can do in Finder easily, the problem is: what to write in the script? I find a suggestion to use "on run argv" and then & item 1 of argv &, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved with:

```
on open fileName
    do shell script "PATH=/Library/TeX/texbin:$PATH open -n -a /Applications/Xournal++.app " & ¬
        quoted form of POSIX path of fileName
end open
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't associate any file type or extension with the app, the handler just receives the files dropped onto the app.

Comment: @red_menace: I know, I changed the title of the question, because it not was clear to me what I was doing or asking :)

Comment: The `PATH` assignment is superfluous, and the first `¬` really should be throwing an error as it's not something any shell I'm aware of would recognise and be happy with.

Comment: @CJK: yes, the string should go on a single line, corrected. But the PATH assignment is not superflous, because without it the program does not file the program "pdflatex".

Answer (score 1):

Going off the answer you provided:

```
on open fileName
        do shell script "PATH=/Library/TeX/texbin:$PATH ¬
            open -n -a /Applications/Xournal++.app " & ¬
            quoted form of POSIX path of fileName
end open
```

a simpler solution would have been:

```
on open {fileName}
        tell application "Xournal++" to open (fileName as «class furl»)
end open
```

which will work for even non-scriptable applications that accept high level Apple events.  For those that don't, then:

```
on open {fileName}
        tell application id "com.apple.Finder" to open fileName ¬
                using application file "/Applications/Xournal++.app"
end open
```

However, overall, it's curious where you're going through the effort of passing it a file to open, only to have it open the file in some other application.  This is a bit like mounting a mirror on the wall to look at your monitor while using the computer, unless this is actually just a small extract from a larger script.

Comment: This is a great explanation of how to accomplish this. I am equally baffled as to *why* the OP would want this script to exist unless it is indeed a small extract from a larger script.

Comment: The first attempt was to open different instances of the same application, so I needed the "-n" option to "open". Next I realized that I needed to add something to PATH, and I cannot find a better way that using a shell script with the prefix "PATH=something"

Comment: Your solution does not exploit these requirements, so is not useful to me.